# How do we escape a set of strings or characters in GROK

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, grok

I'm new to grok in logstash and I have to parse the following log pattern.

```
Jul 26 09:46:37 abc-lb1 2016-07-26 09:46:37.245 +0200  abc-lb1 WF WARN UNRECOGNIZED_COOKIE 188.200.126.234 50011 10.50.51.25 443 global GLOBAL LOG NONE [Cookie\="_ga" Service-created\="769 days back" Reason\="No valid encrypted pair"] GET example.com/search.action?searchText\=EH-5H&token\=--0----EH-5H-- TLSv1.2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" 188.200.126.234 50011 "-" https://example.com/my-account/login
```

> I need to know How to avoid a set of strings in GROK

In the above logs, repeated time-stamps could be seen, I need to know, how to avoid the strings like:

> Jul 26 09:46:37 abc-lb1

Comment: 1) Unnamed capture 2) Custom Patterns 3) multiple possible matches || Each of these should be asked as a separate question if you still have them after reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Comment: Grok uses `named capature only` attribute by default set to true. Which means in your grok pattern if you do not name the unnecessary fields it will not be added in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need only two fields that is `2016-07-26 09:46:37.245` and `https://example.com/my-account/login` then your grok filter should be as follows:

```
grok{ match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{GREEDYDATA} %{URI:url}"} }
```

You will get the following output:

```
{
  "time": [
    [
      "2016-07-26 09:46:37.245"
    ]
  ],
  "url": [
    [
      "https://example.com/my-account/login"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here you are avoiding the first few fields in your log line by directly starting off with `2016-07-26 09:46:37.245` and you are avoiding everything in between by not naming `%{GREEDYDATA}`. If you name `%{GREEDYDATA}` as `%{GREEDYDATA:data}` then you will the output as follows:

```
{
  "time": [
    [
      "2016-07-26 09:46:37.245"
    ]
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "+0200  abc-lb1 WF WARN UNRECOGNIZED_COOKIE 188.200.126.234 50011 10.50.51.25 443 global GLOBAL LOG NONE [Cookie\\="_ga" Service-created\\="769 days back" Reason\\="No valid encrypted pair"] GET example.com/search.action?searchText\\=EH-5H&token\\=--0----EH-5H-- TLSv1.2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" 188.200.126.234 50011 "-""
    ]
  ],
  "url": [
    [
      "https://example.com/my-account/login"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Now you can apply the same steps to whichever fields you want to avoid.

you can debug the results [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with examples, This helps for newbies.